# Predicate true-for-all?

Tags: scheme, racket, predicate

I have been trying to understand this exercise 8.10 in "simply scheme", but just cannot grasp it in Dr Racket..

It's this one: Write a predicate true-for-all? that takes two arguments, a predicate procedure and a sentence. It should return #t if the predicate argument returns true for every word in the sentence.

> (true-for-all? even? ’(2 4 6 8))
>
> ## T
>
> (true-for-all? even? ’(2 6 3 4))
>
> ## F

I tried the solution:

(define (true-for-all? pred sent)
  (= (count sent) (count (keep pred sent))))

but Dr Racket gives errors like count: arity mismatch.
Is anyone able to rewrite it or at least give some hints. Appreciated a lot:)

Best Regards, 
Eunice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Racket supports many languages. Therefore all programs begins with a `#lang` line that tells Racket which language to use. The dialect of Scheme used in Simply Scheme needs this line:

```
#lang planet dyoo/simply-scheme:2
```

The following program:

```
#lang planet dyoo/simply-scheme:2

(define (true-for-all? pred sent)
  (= (count sent) (count (keep pred sent))))

(true-for-all? even? '(2 4 6 8))

(true-for-all? even? '(2 6 3 4))
```

returns

```
#t
#f
```

as expected.

Note: In the lower left corner of DrRacket choose "Determine language from source".

The documentation for the Simply Scheme languages is here: http://planet.racket-lang.org/package-source/dyoo/simply-scheme.plt/2/2/planet-docs/manual/index.html

Comment: that was really informative, thank you very much @soegaard.
But is it also possible to come up with a solution without changing the dialect of Scheme?

Comment: @euniceyoon If you find the answer complete, don't forget to accept it (hit the green check mark).

Answer (score 0):

There's a solution in pure Racket (just for context):

```
#lang racket
(define  (true-for-all? pred list)
  (cond
    [(empty? list) #t]
    [(pred (first list)) (true-for-all? pred (rest list))]
    [else #f]))
```